# how to insert or update both input field value and textarea field (contains mutiple rows/columns) values in to same mysql table?

Tags: php, mysql

how to insert or update both input field values and textarea field (contains mutiple rows/columns) values in to same mysql table using php form submission

here is the php code below:

```
<?php
//invoice.php  
include('../includes/config.php');

if(isset($_POST["add"]))
{
    $comma = preg_replace('/,\\s*/', "', '", $_POST["stateandmileslist"]);
    $row = preg_replace('/\\n/', "'), \n('", $comma);
    $final = "('" . $row . "')";
    $query = "insert into tble_states_miles (states, miles) values \n" . $final;
    $statement = $dbh->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute();
}
?>
```

Thanks to author for above code. It works fine to replace and insert comma separated values in to mysql table. Now my problem is how to insert or update some extra field values in same mysql table

https://stackoverflow.com/users/5563083/paul-spiegel

[image: here is my sql table field]

here is my sql table field

my form code

```
<form method="post">
    <table align="center" style="width: 55%">
        <tr><td><input type="text" name="order_no" value="<?php echo $row["order_no"]; ?>" readonly="">
        </td></tr>

        <tr><td>
            <textarea name="stateandmileslist" class="form-control" rows="10" placeholder="" required></textarea>
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td>
            <input type="submit" name="add" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add" />
        </td></tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: This is a SQL injection attack waiting to happen.

Comment: You are not using prepared statements properly. You need to use parameter binding so that the data will be inserted properly and securely. Here are the instructions for [PDO](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: A bit of code indentation makes php and html soo much easier to read

Comment: thanks guys for your valuable reply. i will properly changed to pdo version no problem..but can you please tell me answer for my question...